# Correct way to do Min-Max normalization

Tags: opencv, math, image-processing, machine-learning, svm

I am implementing alphabet classification using opencv svm. 
I have doubt in normalizing feature vector. 
I have two ways of normalizing feature vector, 
I need to find which is logically correct normalization method ??

**Method 1**

Suppose I have 3 feature vector as follows

```
[2,  3,  8, 5 ] -> image 1
[3,  5,  2, 5 ] -> image 2
[9,  3,  8, 5 ] -> image 3
```

And each value in feature vector is obtained by convolving the pixel with a kernal.

Currently I am finding maximum and minimum value of the each column and doing normalization based on that.

In the above case first column is `[2, 3, 9]`

```
min = 2
max = 9
```

and normalization of first column is done based on that. Likewise all other columns are normalized

**Method 2**

If the kernal is as follows

```
[-1   0  1]
[-1   0  1]
[-1   0  1]
```

then maximum and minimum value can obtained by convolving with above kernel is as follows (8 bit image- Intensity range: 0-255)

```
max val = 765
min val = -765
```

And normalize every value with above max min ?

Which is logically correct way to do normalization (method-1 or method-2) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard way to do it is method-1 (see the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15436367/svm-scaling-input-values)). I also recommend you to read [this paper](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/papers/guide/guide.pdf) for a good reference about svm training.

However, in you case, the range of all features computed with the same kernel will be similar , and method-1 may hurt more than it helps (for example by increasing noise of almost constant features).

So my advice would be : test both methods, and evalute performances to see what works best in your case.

Comment: If our feature are unrelated such as (angle, weight, brightness, etc) then normalizing each column with different min-max values wont create problem). In my case I am extracting features from each zone, so I thing the order of faeture is important (so i thought in this case we should use min-max as in method2)