# svm from e1071 produces wrong results

Tags: r, svm

I'am trying to use `svm` from `e1071` and before going too far with heavy data I intended to play with toy examples.

Here's what I am doing, and I don't understand why it obviously doesn't work.

```
# generate some silly 2D data
X = data.frame(x1 = runif(10), x2 = runif(10))
# attach a label according to position above/below diagonal x+y=1
X$y <- rep(1, 10)
X$y[(X$x1 + X$x2)<1] = -1
X$y <- factor(X$y)
# train svm model
require(e1071)
meta <- svm(y~., data = X, kernel = "linear", scale = FALSE)
# visualize the result
plot(meta, X)
```

[image: plot.svm]

So from this point on the graph error is already visible because there are some misclassified points and classifier is not the one I'm expecting (all vectors are supports especially).

If I want to predict then, it's wrong too:

```
predict(meta, newdata = X[,-3])==X$y
[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

If I want to do manual prediction I can't get it working too:

```
omega <- t(meta$coefs)%*%meta$SV
pred <- c(-sign(omega%*%t(X[,-3]) - meta$rho))
pred==X$y
 [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

I'm sure there is something I am missing, but can't figure out what !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there are two separate problems here, your model and your plot. The model is easy to solve, but the plot is more confusing.

**Too many support vectors and incorrect predictions**

SVM usually works with scaled inputs (mean=0, sd=1). See [this explanation of why SVM takes scaled inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15436367/svm-scaling-input-values).

You can either scale your inputs first, using the base R `scale` function or set `scale=TRUE` when calling `svm`. I suggest scaling manually, for better control:

```
X <- as.data.frame(scale(data.frame(x1 = runif(10), x2 = runif(10))))
X$y <- rep(1, 10)
X$y[(X$x1 + X$x2)<0] <- -1
X$y <- factor(X$y)
require(e1071)
meta <- svm(y~., data = X, kernel = "linear")
```

You should now have a sensible number of support vectors:

```
meta

  Call:
  svm(formula = y ~ ., data = X, kernel = "linear")


  Parameters:
     SVM-Type:  C-classification 
   SVM-Kernel:  linear 
         cost:  1 
        gamma:  0.5 

  Number of Support Vectors:  4
```

Predictions should now also be perfect:

```
predict(meta, newdata = X[,-3])==X$y
 [1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

**Plotting the SVM**

I still have the same problem as you when I plot the SVM, though: several "x" and "o" labels lie on the wrong side of the decision boundary.

Yet if I plot it manually using `ggplot`, the results look correct:

```
plotgrid <- expand.grid(seq(-2, 2, 0.1), seq(-2, 2, 0.1))
names(plotgrid) <- c("x1", "x2")
plotgrid$y <- predict(meta, newdata=plotgrid)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(plotgrid) +
    geom_point(aes(x1, x2, colour=y)) +
    geom_text(data=X, aes(x1, x2, label=ifelse(y==-1, "O", "X"))) +
    ggtitle("Manual SVM Plot")
```

[image: Manual SVM Plot]

So at least we know the underlying SVM model is correct. Indeed, the decision boundary is plotted correctly by `plot.svm` (you can confirm this by swapping the x1 and x2 axes in your `ggplot` call, to match the axis labels that `plot.svm` uses as default).

The problem appears to be that `plot.svm` is labelling the points incorrectly. I am not sure why. If anyone knows, please leave a comment and I will update this answer. In the meantime, I hope the `ggplot` workaround will suffice.

Comment: thanks for digging into this problem. As far as I know about svm, even though the prediction is right, the svm is wrong: according to your plot there should be 3 support vectors, and the separation should have probably more of less the same slope but a higher intercept

Comment: By the strict "maximal margin" definition of SVM, I think you're right. But have a look at Page 6 of https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/papers/guide/guide.pdf (the whole paper is worth reading, by the way). I think the LibSVM calculation is more complicated, and involves "slack" variables, hence there are extra support vectors. This is to avoid overfitting and make use of more data.

Comment: I got your point; indeed I was thinking that for such an easy example these slacks variables won't change anything